# Check if request to server was made by ionic app

Tags: php, html, css, security, ionic-framework

Right now we have a Ionic project that is almost finished that comes with a php backend. To make the backend a little bit more secure against influences from outsite we would like to make the backend only accessible from within the ionic project (native app). I tried to restrict it by domain but since a native app doesn't have a domain that's not gonna work.

I can't show any code because i'm absolutely clueless on how to approach this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought about sending a unique token in a header in each request? JWT is generally used for authentication but can technically carry whatever information you like, you can verify it server side and proceed with the request.

Comment: I'm not really sure how that flow would look like. Ofcourse i would be able to verify it serverside but I can't directly generate one within the app.

Comment: When you load the app, you grab the token and save it locally, then update the token when needed (JWT expires after x time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> we would like to make the backend only accessible from within the ionic project (native app).

Given the existence of reverse engineering and the futility of DRM, [what you're asking for is, strictly speaking, not possible](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem) in absolute terms. Anyone can take your app, analyze its code/behavior (usually with freely available tools), and write their own app that communicates with your server.

> To make the backend a little bit more secure against influences from outsite

Given that the above is impossible, what is your threat model? What attacks are you trying to protect against? You should assume that clients are malicious and validate all input on the server side. If you do that, then you don't need to worry about whether or not someone used your native app to communicate with the server.

Consider the workflow in this article, [Building Secure Web Applications in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/building-secure-web-applications-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, allright i understand what your saying. What i'm trying to avoid is that people can analyze the code of the app -> find the path to the backend -> run pages in browser without using the app.

With security like sql injection etc. we have been carefull. But it would be great if i could prevent users from executing pages on backend without making use of the app.

Comment: "But it would be great if i could prevent users from executing pages on backend without making use of the app." Sorry, that's strictly impossible.